# I have a script code which works, but how do I make this script code more "elegant"?

Tags: awk

Some background. I have two files (A and B) which contain data I need to extract.

For file A, I only need the last two lines which look like this:

```
RMM:  17    -0.221674395053E+01    0.59892E-04    0.00000E+00    31   0.259E-03
    1 F= -.22167440E+01 E0= -.22167440E+01  d E =-.398708E-10  mag=     2.0000
```

I need to extract the following numbers:

```
-1st Line, 2nd field (17)
-1st Line 4th field (0.59892E-04)
-2nd Line, 1st field (1)
-2nd Line, 3rd field (-.22167440E+01)
-2nd Line, 5th field (-.22167440E+01)
-2nd Line, 8th field (-.398708E-10)
-2nd Line, 10th field (2.0000)
```

For file B, I only need the last 11 lines which look like this:

```
                  Total CPU time used (sec):        0.364
                        User time (sec):        0.355
                      System time (sec):        0.009
                     Elapsed time (sec):        1.423

               Maximum memory used (kb):        9896.
               Average memory used (kb):           0.

                      Minor page faults:         2761
                      Major page faults:            4
             Voluntary context switches:           24
```

I need to extract the following numbers:

```
 -1st line, 6th field (0.364)
 -2nd line, 4th field (0.355)
 -3rd line, 4th field (0.009)
 -4th line, 4th field (1.423)
 -6th line, 5th field (9896.)
 -7th line, 5th field (0.)
```

My output should be like this:

```
mainfolder1[tab/space]subfolder1[tab/space][all the extracted info separated by tab]
mainfolder2[tab/space]subfolder2[tab/space][all the extracted info separated by tab]
mainfolder3[tab/space]subfolder3[tab/space][all the extracted info separated by tab]
...
mainfoldern[tab/space]subfoldern[tab/space][all the extracted info separated by tab]
```

Now this is my script code:

```
for m in ./*/; do
main=$(basename "$m")
for s in "$m"*/; do
    sub=$(basename "$s")
vdata=$(tail -n2 ./$main/$sub/A | awk -F'[ =]+' NR==1'{a=$2;b=$4;next}{print s,a,$2,$4,$6,$9, $11}')
ctime=$(tail -n11 ./$main/$sub/B |head -n1|awk '{print $6}')
utime=$(tail -n10 ./$main/$sub/B |head -n1|awk '{print $4}')
stime=$(tail -n9 ./$main/$sub/B |head -n1|awk '{print $4}')
etime=$(tail -n8 ./$main/$sub/B |head -n1|awk '{print $4}')
maxmem=$(tail -n6 ./$main/$sub/B |head -n1|awk '{print $5}')
avemem=$(tail -n5 ./$main/$sub/B |head -n1|awk '{print $5}')
c=$(echo $sub| cut -c 2-)
    echo "$m $c $vdata $ctime $utime $stime $etime $maxmem $avemem"
done
done > output
```

Now, the fourth line, the vdata part, was actually a "recycled" line from a previous forum question. I do not fully understand it. I wanted my file B codes to be as a elegant as that awk code for file A. How do I do it? Thank you! :)

Comment: `-F'[ =]+'` on the `vdata` line is adding `=` to the value of `FS` (field split) for awk so that field `$8` doesn't contain the leading `=`. The `NR==1{...}` block is storing the values from the first line for use in the second line's print output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1{print $6} NR==2{print $4} NR==3{print $4} ...'
```

You could simplify a bit with:

```
NR==2 || NR==3 || NR==4
```

but that seems hard to maintain.  Or you could use an array:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a[1]=6;a[2]=4...} NR in a{ print $a[NR]}'
```

But I think you really just want:

```
awk '{print $NF}' ORS=\\t
```

(You don't want the 6th field from row 1.  You want the last field.)

Rather than trying to collect the output into variables just to be echoed, add `ORS=\\t` to get tab separated output, and just let it print to stdout of the script.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was very neat, I think I will use yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

For file B try something like:

```
tail -n11 B | awk -F':' '{ print $2 }'
```

if you need to retain the values and then echo, you could do something like:

```
array=($(tail -n11 B | awk -F':' '{ print $2 }'))
for value in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo $value
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `find` and `xargs` since every time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach BUT to keep it simple and retain your original structure, it sounds like you could use something like:

```
for m in ./*/; do
  main=$(basename "$m")
  for s in "$m"*/; do
    sub=$(basename "$s")
    fileA="${main}/${sub}/A"
    fileB="${main}/${sub}/B"
    awk -v sizeA=$(wc -l < "$fileA") -v sizeB=$(wc -l < "$fileB") '
        NR==FNR {
            if ( FNR == (sizeA-1) ) { split($0,p) }
            if ( FNR == sizeA )     { split($0,a) }
            next
        }
        { b[sizeB + 1 - FNR] = $NF }
        END {
            split(FILENAME,f,"/")
            print f[1], f[2], p[2], p[4], a[1], a[3], a[5], a[8], a[10], b[11], b[10], b[9], b[8], b[6], b[5]
        }
    ' "$fileA" "$fileB"
  done
done > output
```

Note that the above only opens each "B" file 1 time instead of 6.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into find and xargs. :)